# Can I replace those arrow icons with some other controls

Tags: gui-design, controls

**Situation:** I have a GUI containing different rows. At the end of each row there is an arrow indicating you might show some more info by clicking on that arrow. I do not think this is a good solution because:

1. The control has to be more "visual obvious".
2. The "click area" has to increase.
3. It has to  be more obvious what the control actually does.

**Question:** Is there a better way to open/close a textblock instead of using those arrows (one marked with a circle in the image below)?

Oh, and never mind the language (it's in Swedish), please just focus on the input.

[image]

Comment: You might try putting the arrows on the left-hand side, where they will be more visible to users (at least in the target LTR locale).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If those are you requirements:

> The control has to be more "visual obvious".
>
> The "click area" has to increase.
>
> It has to be more obvious what the control actually does.

Then why wouldn't you use a **labeled button**?

[image]

Comment: Thanks @asiegfried , I think i'll stick to your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how would it be in Swedish, but it seems to me that if you don't want the arrows (which are pretty clear and recognized by most users) you could simply use a combination of the words *more / less*. For better scanning and affordance, underline them and make them the color of your links.

Alternatively, you could also use the + / - signs, but I don't think it's as clear as the arrows. However, if you decide to use them, do not enclose them in a circle since iOS users understand this as the icon *for the user to add something* rather than to *see more*.